# vcpkg installation of matplotlib-cpp

Tags: c++, matplotlib, vcpkg

I would like to use the `matplotlib-cpp` functionality in my c++ code. I installed `vcpkg` on my Windows 10 machine however, I get the following error when trying to `install matplotlib-cpp`. Any ideas?

```
$ ./vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    matplotlib-cpp[core]:x86-windows -> 2020-08-27
Could not locate a complete toolset.
The following paths were examined:

username@DESKTOP-UB67JME MINGW64 /c/vcpkg (master)
```

** UPDATE **
Ran from PowerShell and got the following errors. Most likely same issue.

PS C:\vcpkg> .\vcpkg install matplotib-cpp
Computing installation plan...
Error: while loading matplotib-cpp:
The port directory (C:\vcpkg\ports\matplotib-cpp) does not exist
Error: failed to load port from C:\vcpkg\ports\matplotib-cpp
Note: Updating vcpkg by rerunning bootstrap-vcpkg may resolve this failure.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a compiler installed (or if you do vcpkg can't find it anyway).

Comment: I do have a g++ compiler installed as I have been using VS Code for C++. I suspect it may have something to do with Python installation which was performed using miniconda.

Comment: x86-windows requires visual studio and the cl compiler. You either want a different triplet or need to install VS

Comment: @feistranch Hello. Have you solved this issue ? I am struggle to use matplotlib-cpp into a simple cpp console app and I don't make it ...

Comment: @flaviu2 I did not. I ended up re-writing the Python code to C.